# MySQL Sub-partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have the following MySQL table that is currently partitioned.

I want to add sub-partitioning on the 'message_read' key - this is to optimize searches through partitions for un-read messages.

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `pid` int(50) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `userid1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Message Sender',
  `userid2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Message Receiver',
  `message` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Actual Message',
  `message_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=Not Read & 1=Read',
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date Time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`,`datetime`),
  KEY `userid1` (`userid1`),
  KEY `userid2` (`userid2`),
  KEY `message_read` (`message_read`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(`datetime`))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (735234) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (735265) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (735293) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (735324) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (735354) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (735385) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (735415) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Current partition is on datetime stamp. How could I add into sub-partitioning on 'message_read'?

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add message_read to the primary key.
Then (You can use hash or key for sub-partitioning):

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `pid` INT(50) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `userid1` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Message Sender',
  `userid2` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Message Receiver',
  `message` TEXT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Actual Message',
  `message_read` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=Not Read & 1=Read',
  `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date Time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`,`datetime`, message_read),
  KEY `userid1` (`userid1`),
  KEY `userid2` (`userid2`),
  KEY `message_read` (`message_read`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(`datetime`))
SUBPARTITION BY HASH (message_read)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (735234)(SUBPARTITION s0, SUBPARTITION s1),
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (735265)(SUBPARTITION s2, SUBPARTITION s3),
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (735293)(SUBPARTITION s4, SUBPARTITION s5),
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (735324)(SUBPARTITION s6, SUBPARTITION s7),
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (735354)(SUBPARTITION s8, SUBPARTITION s9),
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (735385)(SUBPARTITION s10, SUBPARTITION s11),
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (735415)(SUBPARTITION s12, SUBPARTITION s13)) ;
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Thanks,
y

Answer (score 0):

In this case - Since each partition is devided into two parts,
How will mysql devide the record to the subpartitions?
after all mysql don't know how many records will be entered into each partition/subpartition